# Is there an Real-Time Object Detection algorithm for CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, yolo

I need to use some object detection algorithms in real time (will detect stuff while driving).
So far I've managed to use YOLO-v3 with pytorch on a GPU pc with great results.

Is there an algorithm I can use on an ~1.6GHz CPU on a laptop? 
My current net is detecting on the CPU with ~5 second per frame which is too slow for realtime...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes absolutely, a pc with high-speed internet and combo it with Kaggle, Google Colab, or renting a tensor workstation from Google VM. Yolov3 has been the most efficient algorithm out there to perform nearly instant object recognition. Having a 1.6 Ghz can't bring you any where to far, unless you spend extra bucks on a GTX 1060 and above.

Comment: Yes you can use YOLO and tensorflow to do the computation on your CPU.
But that will not be as good as if you do on GPU. But there might be a lag, you GPU for better performance.